# Java - DateTimeFormatter - ParseException

Tags: java, exception, localdate

I have this really strange problem of a small snippet of code working on one machine, and not another. This code:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    Map<LocalDate, Double> temperatur = new TreeMap<>();
    for (LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.parse("2014-jan-01", formatter); currentDate.getYear() < 2015; currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1))
    {
        String date = currentDate.toString();
        int stringIndex = (data.indexOf(date));
        String tempString = data.substring((stringIndex + 31), (stringIndex + 35));
        if(tempString.contains(";"))
            tempString = tempString.substring(0, 3);
        double temp = Double.parseDouble(tempString);
        temperatur.put(currentDate, temp);
    }
```

Gives me the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-jan-01' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)
    at main.SMHITest.getValues(SMHITest.java:50)
    at main.DataCollectionBuilder.addToResult(DataCollectionBuilder.java:46)
    at main.DataCollectionBuilder.<init>(DataCollectionBuilder.java:25)
    at main.ClientProgram.main(ClientProgram.java:14)
```

The SMHITest.Java:50 line is as you might guess right at the for loop. The strange part is, this piece of code works fine at one computer, but refuses to work for me at home. Both machines runs Eclipse mars jee, but one machine (where its working) runs java 1.8.0_112, and the other one runs java 1.8.0_121-b13. But i cant imagine that would be the problem?

Comment: Does the "J" of "Jan" need to be capitalized?

Comment: Yes it seems so, because that did it! Thank you! 
Although it's still strange that it was not necessary on the other machine. But ill leave it there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is thrown as it given date "2014-jan-01" doesn't match with format `yyyy-MMM-dd`. It needs to be **2014-Jan-01**

not sure what are you trying to achieve here in the following ,

```
String tempString = data.substring((stringIndex + 31), (stringIndex + 35));

if(tempString.contains(";"))
```

as date  2014-01-0 doesn't contains '**;**' or it has 35 characters in length.

Comment: Yes, just as Keith pointed out the J needed to be capitalized. Which still is weird since its the exakt same (i actually double checked after correcting) code on the other machine. But thank you!

The "data" string is filled with a bunch of data from a json file and is completely out of context here, i probably should have cut that part out.

Comment: LocalDate is introduced in java8 and it should behave same in all machines.I guess you must be missing something else.

Comment: Yeah, your probably right. I'm just really confused of what. But i guess ill just have to move on now that it's working. It bugs me though, haha.

Comment: always remember famous catch "java code write once run anywhere"  :)

Comment: Haha, i dont know how i feel about that one right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only (and awkward) way to **parse such a string like "2014-jan-01" in a case-insensitive way** using the new `java.time`-API is as follows:

```
String input = "2014-jan-01";
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive().appendPattern("uuuu-MMM-dd")
    .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = dtf.parse(input, LocalDate::from);
System.out.println(date); // 2014-01-01
```